# using regex with conflicting and overlapping path names

Tags: nginx, routing

consider the following regex, where I'm trying to route the requests of the format `/customers/:id/products` to **customerproduct** domain.

I've put this conflicting overlapping rule **first in the sequence** to give it priority because location `/customers` also accepts `/customers/1`

Can someone please help me with the following routes, i'm new to nginx.

```
server {
    location /customers/[0-9]+/products {
        proxy_pass http://customerproduct:3000
    }

    location /customers {
        proxy_pass http://customer:3000;
    }

    location /products {
        proxy_pass http://product:3000;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

fixing

```
location ~/customers/[0-9]+/products {
    proxy_pass http://customerproduct:3000;
}
```

**Edit 2**

fix 2.

```
server {
    location ^/customers/[0-9]+/products {
        proxy_pass http://customerproduct:3000
    }

    location ^/customers {
        proxy_pass http://customer:3000;
    }

    location ^/products {
        proxy_pass http://product:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. sorry my bad, i'm new to nginx, is my edit correct?

Comment: thanks, it's working now.

Comment: sorry didn't get you on about the start of the URI, can you please help with the code answer, would really appreciate it.

Comment: See edit 2 please, kindly confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax and order of evaluation of location blocks is detailed in the [manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

The first location block is intended to use a regular expression, which needs the `~` or `~*` operator to indicate that. Also, a regular expression that should match the beginning of the URI should include the `^` anchor.

For example:

```
server {
    location ~ ^/customers/[0-9]+/products {
        proxy_pass http://customerproduct:3000;
    }

    location /customers {
        proxy_pass http://customer:3000;
    }

    location /products {
        proxy_pass http://product:3000;
    }
}
```

The remaining locations are prefix locations, so the order of the blocks is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I appreciate your help